# geth attach not working

Tags: go-ethereum

1. Type `get attach` (an error appears: `fatal:unable to attach to remote geth: timed out waiting for pipe '\\,pipe\geth.ipc'to come available`)
2. Type `eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.coinbase, to: "RECEIVER ACCOUNT", value: web3.toWei(1.00, "ether")})` (an error appears: `web3.from wei is not recognized as an external internal command,operable program or batch`).

Can anyone help me with this ?
Regards

Comment: 1) Is geth running? Make sure both are launched with same permission, ie both run as user and not as Administrator. 2) Where are you executing those commands from? What is your exact command? The error is about `fromWei` but it is not in your command.